# Solution for showing facebook comments on my WP posts from two App ID/API Key

Tags: facebook-graph-api, wordpress, facebook-comments

I have built up a new Facebook application for my WordPress site.

I have connected it to my site by "add link to facebook" plugin.

Now my issue is all my past Facebook posts comments (comment integration) are not showing up...How can I pull them back from the old application?

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin code, add `xid="URL"` and `migrated="1"` to the `fb:comments` tag, and it should migrate old comments from the URL to the new app.

The comments are tied to the URL and not the App ID, so as long as you have the correct `data-href` parameter set, you comments should appear correctly.